# zsh: command not found: flutter?

Tags: flutter, zsh, macos-catalina

I've tried to install flutter multiple times, and could run flutter doctor once, but after closing the terminal I couldn't. Don't know how I did it, and this keeps coming on the screen.

```
user@users-MacBook-Pro flutter % export PATH="$PATH: /Users/user/Desktop/flutter/bin"
user/users-MacBook-Pro flutter % flutter --version
zsh: command not found: flutter
user@users-MacBook-Pro flutter %
```

So I have changed my path, changed the shell to -zsh, because I work with macOS Catalina, but nothing seems to work. What should I do?

Comment: You should restart your terminal and try again

Comment: `PATH` is colon-separated, not colon+space-separated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Open Terminal and Type: 
`vim $HOME/.zshrc`
After that, we need to edit that file!
Press command I
Now on a new line Type:
`export PATH="$PATH:/YOUR_FILE_PATH/flutter/bin` Don't forget to update `YOUR_FILE_PATH`!
Now press `esc`
Now type `:wq!` to exit
Now *restart* your terminal

Answer (score 14):

As Lesiak said, you need to remove the space in your string, leaving you with `export PATH="$PATH:/Users/user/Desktop/flutter/bin"`. However, this will only change the current shell (terminal) you have open.

To make this permanent, you need to change your *zsh configuration file*. This is located at `$HOME/.zshrc`. Run this command:

```sh
$ echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/$HOME/Desktop/flutter/bin"' >> $HOME/.zshrc
```

This appends `export PATH="$PATH:/$HOME/Desktop/flutter/bin"` to the end your `.zshrc` file. **Note that it is crucial that you use `>>` and not `>`**. `>>` appends to the file, `>` **overwrites** it.

To further explain what's going on here:

`$HOME` refers to your *home directory*. On your machine, and if your user is called `user`, this would be `/Users/user`. This would vary based on the type of operating system you have and your username, therefore we use `$HOME` to be device-independent.

`$PATH` is where your shell looks for programs to execute when you type a command in the shell. If you do `echo $PATH` you can see its content. It could look something like this: `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`. All the parts separated by `:` is a segment of the path, and your shell looks in each of those directories for a program that matches the command you gave.

Answer (score 5):

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

Type this command in Terminal. This work for me.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the empty space in

```
export PATH="$PATH: /Users/user/Desktop/flutter/bin"
```

Comment: This is work, but temporary solution, Thanks !!!

Answer (score 3):

Open Terminal and Type:

```
vim $HOME/.zshrc
```

After that, we need to edit that file!
Press command <kbd>I</kbd>

Now on a new line Type:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/YOUR_FILE_PATH/flutter/bin
```

Don't forget to update YOUR_FILE_PATH!

Now press esc

Now type `:wq!` to exit

Now restart your terminal

Answer (score 2):

Try this one that is in the official documentation. https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/macos

```
export PATH="$PATH:`pwd`/flutter/bin"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
export PATH=$PATH:/'Your Path'/flutter/bin\
```

example :-
export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/Flutter/flutter/bin\

this is work for me

Answer (score 1):

Type this command in Terminal. This work for me.

```
export PATH="$PATH:`pwd`/flutter/bin"
```

Comment: OK, its working after executing this command. But why I need to do it every-time when running flutter command?

Answer (score 1):

The .zshrc file is not present by default sometimes, we need to create it.

Steps for creation:

Open Terminal ->
type  `touch ~/.zshrc` to create the respective file.

To open the file -> type `open $HOME/.zshrc`

or

Open Finder > Press `Cmd + Shift + ~`

Answer (score 1):

FolloW These Steps For Permanent Solution
[image]

[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks man, finally I got it running!! 

Answer (score 0):

1. Open terminal
2. Write => vim .bash_profile

   OR => vim $HOME/.zshrc
3. Click on (i) to be able to insert the following:

   Write => export PATH="$PATH:[PATH_OF_FLUTTER_GIT_DIRECTORY]/bin"

   OR => export PATH=[PATH_OF_FLUTTER_GIT_DIRECTORY]/bin:$PATH
4. Click on (esc) to be able back from inserting mode
5. Write => :wq! [This will exit]
6. Restart terminal then Write => flutter doctor

- The problem will be easily solved ^_^