# zsh: command not found: flutter Oh my zsh p10k

Tags: flutter, oh-my-zsh

Trying to run flutter doctor or any other command but I have this prompt

```
zsh: command not found: flutter
```

Prior the installation of oh my zsh and p10k, flutter commands were fine. I am in a Mac book air 2020 with M1 and my OS is Monterrey v12.5.1

Thanks!

**Edit: Now works, my PATH was incomplete hehe**

Comment: REFER [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62639823/zsh-command-not-found-flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62639823/zsh-command-not-found-flutter).

Comment: I did try that command export PATH="$PATH:/Development/flutter/bin, but didn't  work. I put it on the top line, don't know If that matters, plus all the lines in $HOME/.zshrc are with a #.

Comment: DId you try rebootting ?

Comment: :wq! then restarted iTerm2, just overwrites p10k but flutter commands don't work

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.